# Java - split a string to different fields using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Does anyone have an idea how I can split a string returned by a WS to different strings?

```
String wsResult = "SONACOM RC, RUE DES ETOILES N. 20, 75250 PARIS (MI)";
```

I'm trying to split it into:

```
String name = "SONACOM RC";
String adress = "RUE DES ETOILES N. 20";
String postalCode = "75250";
String city = "PARIS";
```

N.B: the return of the WS changes only what is inside of my parameters

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: You need a constant structure in order to use regexes or `.split`. It's not clear from your question if this condition does apply

Comment: Are you sure that there won't be any comma in the address part itself ? If it is the case you can use a regex to find the group. Something like this might work in your case: (.*),(.*), *(\d{5})(.*)       You can check the behavior of regexp online, here for instance: https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Depends how you want to parse that information... `(?<name>[\w .-]+?)\s*,\s*(?<address>[\w .-]+?)\s*,\s*(?<postalCode>\d+)\s*(?<city>[^()]+?)(?:\s+.*)?$` or `\s*,\s*|(?<=\b\d{5})\s+`

Comment: @ctwheels looks like Python regex, isn't it ?

Comment: @Guillaume the regex I posted will work in Java, Python, PCRE, among others.

Comment: I was totally unaware of named group in Java since jdk7! Thanks :)

Comment: I propose you the following regex `([^,]+),([^,]+),\s*(\d+)\s+([^(]+)(?= +\()`.

Comment: Split on comma (if comma's aren't relative) then examine what's left after split. And, who knows the variants of whatever this string represents ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture your data in 4 capturing groups. Your provided example uses uppercase characters, which you can match with `[A-Z]`.
If you want to match also lowercase characters, digits and an underscore, you could replace `[A-Z]` or `[A-Z\d]` with `\w`.
You can go about this in multiple ways. An approach could be:

[`([A-Z ]+), +([A-Z\d .]+), +(\d+) +([A-Z\d() ]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/FP68no/1)

**Explanation**

- **Group 1**: match one or more uppercase characters or a whitespace `([A-Z ]+)`
- Match a comma and one or more whitespaces `, +`
- **Group 2**: match one or more uppercase characters or digit or whitespace or dot `([A-Z\d .]+)`
- Match a comma and one or more whitespaces `, +`
- **Group 3**: match one or more digits `(\d+)`
- Match one or more whitespaces `+`
- **Group 4**: match one or more uppercase characters or digit or open/close parenthesis or whitespace `([A-Z\d() ]+)`

[Output in Java](http://rextester.com/BGW6035)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to split it as you'd like is using `wsResult.split(",")`. However, you'll have to add a comma between `75250` and `Paris`:

```
String wsResult = "SONACOM RC, RUE DES ETOILES N. 20, 75250, PARIS (MI)";
String[] temp = wsResult.split(",");
String name = temp[0];
String adress = temp[1];
String postalCode = temp[2];
String city = temp[3];
```

Using that you will get the output you're looking for.

**EDIT**

Another way to get your output without adding a comma would be to do this (using the code above too):

```
for(int i = 1; i<postalCode.length(); i++){

    if(postalCode.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        city = postalCode.substring(i,postalCode.length());
        postalCode = postalCode.substring(0,i);
        break;
    }

}
```

For more information check [the String class in the API Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).